# Forcing the use of an index can improve performance?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Imagine that we have a query like this:

```
select a.col1, b.col2
from t1 a
inner join t2 b on a.col1 = b.col2
where a.col1 = 'abc'
```

Both `col1` and `col2` don't have any index.

---

If I add another restriction on the where clause, one that is always correct but with a column with an index:

```
select a.col1, b.col2
from t1 a
inner join t2 b on a.col1 = b.col2
where a.col1 = 'abc'
and a.id >= 0  -- column always true and with index
```

**May the query perform faster since it may use the index on `id` column?**

Comment: Unless `and a.id >= 0` reduces the number of rows, probably not

Comment: It's possible that there is an index that is used in the second case that the optimizer wouldn't have chosen for the first.  For example, a composite index for table `t1` on columns `id` and `col1` may not appear the help the first query, but allows the second query to reduce I/O due to the (assumed) greater density of index entries per page compared to table rows per page.

Comment: @HABO well spotted, it might be something like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index on `id` to do what?

The most costly bit here is the join on the join columns, and `id` has nothing to do with that.

Most likely scenario, it makes no difference.

Possible outcome: It makes it take more, because it doesn't work out that `id` is always greater than zero, so it makes an index scan to find the correct rows, and then from that obtains the same rows it would have gotten from an table-scan (it would be different perhaps if there was a `INCLUDE` covering the columns in question).

Outlandish outcome: Well, stranger things have happened in the world of database optimisation, so I wouldn't eat my hat if it helped, but I'd still be mightily surprised.

Really though, forcing irrelevant work with irrelevant indices is not going to help your cause.

Edit: Actually I thought of a case where it can help. SQLServer will generally use some index to seek upon, in the absence of a directly relevant one, because seek generally does better than scan even in that case. Forcing a seek upon a different index could *just* feasibly improve things, if for some reason that seek was better and for some reason it picked a different one to seek on. I'd still be pretty surprised though.

Comment: Ok, thanks Walter White :P I've put this question because some people use it in DB2 here at the bank, and for some reason it's much faster..

Comment: @aF. Walter White? Ah well, I suppose it's better than Anton LaVey.

Comment: Can you get an analysis of why it helps? I remember `where id=id` helping a query once for similar enough reasons, but thought that was very much a thing of the past. (And besides, just add the indices that'll really help).

Comment: Regarding DB2 I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: Regarding Anton Lavey (satanist, etc.) and Walter White (drug lord, etc.) I don't know which is better to be :P

Comment: When you also write about occultism and religion - fictional drug lord leads to much fewer prior assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly (but improbably). This is all down to the way the query optimiser evaluates you query. A better option would be to use hints.

Answer (score 1):

i think it would be actually worse.  since if it used an index here to retrieve all rows, then that is extra work compared to simply retrieving all rows.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is yes, it can improve performance if it filters out enough of the rows of table a.